# How to apply torque impulse

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque

In the below question, can we apply conservation of Angular Momentum? If not, why?

Moreover how do we apply Torque impulse to the system ?
The contact force between the cylinders will be normal to the surface and passing through the axis of rotation so wouldn't the torque due to them would be 0?

[image: The question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @Dhiraj_Barnwal is questioning as to whether or not the problem can be solved and so it is a valid query.

If you consider any of the answers to be true and conserve angular momentum then energy conservation is violated.
If angular momentum is not conserved then there must be a external torque acting on the system of three cylinders and that external torque is provided by the bearings/supports/ Earth which hold the outer two axles axles in place.

If you consider the left hand cylinder then the middle cylinder will exert a downward frictional force on it.  To stop the left hand cylinder centre of mass moving its axle must have an upward force on it provided by the bearing.  Those two forces acting on the left hand cylinder form a couple which is in an opposite direction to its rotation and so the angular momentum of the cylinder decreases.  The same is true for the right hand cylinder.

For the middle cylinder which has two equal magnitude opposite direction frictional forces acting on it there is no force at the axle but a couple which is twice as large as that on the other two cylinders.

The final state with no slipping between the cylinders is the cylinders all rotating with the same angular speed.